# Python yield and return statements? and Scrapy Yielding the requests

Tags: python, scrapy

What is the difference between `yield` and `return` explain with example?
and what actually happens when in the generator we `yield` any value or request?

I'm not calling my generator from any other function or program.

My loop is:

```
for index in range(3):
  yield Request(url,callback=parse)
```

This is making requests on the specific url and calling the callback function after the request. What this code is  doing?

And what is the sequence followed by the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Python yield keyword explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Comment: no, but its in more detail and relevent to a some exammple for SCRAPY Request Object.

Comment: Did you read the question linked to?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are faced with the puzzle in the function `start_requests()` with the context `yield` in it.

For example:

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

When you refer to the document of scrapy [spider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) and then find the function named `start_requests()`,it says the method must return an iterable. If you change yield to return, it is not an iterable because the for loop is already over when you start your spider.It could be a mess.

It is natural that your spider should send http requests to these destinations one by one so the best way is a generator. In the for loop, your spider will stop at `yield` and return `scrapy.Request()`, with all things done, your spider will `send()` to generator and move on to next 
following urls in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The only aspect of your question that isn't answered by the question linked to by @Jochen is "i am not calling my generator from any other function or program.".

You define your crawler class, and scrapy calls the (special) functions you define, as specified in the documentation. (For example the [`parse`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.parse) function is the default callback for requests that don't specify a callback).